# How to refresh UserFrosting UFTable without updating filters

Tags: php, jquery, tablesorter, userfrosting

Our UserFrosting (4.2) application has a dashboard page which shows recent data using a `ufTable` object. We would like to automatically refresh the table contents every 60 seconds.

The idea is that this table will be displayed on a monitor in the workroom to show the current status of various on-going operations, and we'd like it to automatically refresh just the data without having to add an interval to the entire page itself to refresh the page.

We tried a variety of ways to solve this, including re-initializing the table every x many milliseconds. But, the table doesn't actually refresh upon re-initializing the object as there is a flag in the `ufTable` wrapper intended to improve performance by not needlessly re-querying the server. I believe it is this flag that prevents the re-initialization from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edit] Documentation has been added to support the `refresh()` method. Usage below.

It turns out if you examine the source code of the table you'll see a refresh method does exist, but there's no documentation for this in the [official documentation](https://learn.userfrosting.com/client-side-code/components/tables#methods). To work around this, use the following code:
`$("#your-widget-id").ufTable("refresh");`

Comment: Yes, this was added in 4.2. Might indeed be missing from documentation.,

Comment: A PR was added to the UF docs and this is now resolved in the documentation as well